# configuration generator in Scala

Tags: scala, configuration, generator, configuration-files

Let say that I have a generic component implemented in Scala (like the one sugested from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531913/how-to-use-generics-in-scala)):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

sealed trait Language {
  val messages: Map[String, String]
}
class English extends Language {
  val messages: Map[String, String] =
    Map("M01" -> "Ready for cooking - press START",
      "M02" -> "Close the door to start cooking")
}
class French extends Language {
  val messages: Map[String, String] =
    Map("M01" -> "Pret pour la cuisson - presse START",
      "M02" -> "Fermez la porte pour commencer la cuisson")
}
class Lang[A <: Language] {

  private var language: Language = new English

  def chosen(lang: A): Unit = {
    language = lang
  }

  def displayMessage(msg: String): Unit = {
    println(language messages msg) 
  }

}
```

My concern is how I can built a configuration generator (I am refering in the terminology of C++) to configure this component? At least any reference? Or another way, how I can use a configuration file for example to configure it?

Comment: Is your concern specifically related to i18n?

Comment: @Nader Hadji Ghanbari, noo, not at all. I am just thinking to find a way and to configure a bunch of such components differenly. Maybe building a DSL that can configure them!

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a way to handle translations through a config file have a look at [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config). In this specific case you'd have something like the following:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
import com.typesafe.config.Config
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

//within some object/class/...you got it
def loadMessages(config: Config, lang: String): Map[String, String] = config.getObject(lang).asScala map { case (k, v) => k -> v.unwrapped.toString }
```

Your config file would contain something like the following:

```
translation {     
  english {  
    M01 = "Ready for cooking - press START"  
    M02 = "Close the door to start cooking"  
  }  
  french {  
    M01 = "Pret pour la cuisson - presse START"  
    M02 = "Fermez la porte pour commencer la cuisson"  
  }  
}
```

Then load your config file and get the translation map as follows:

```
val config: Config = // load your config file. See Typesafe Config for details

val translationCfg = config.getConfig("translation")

val english = loadMessages(translationCfg, "english")
val french = loadMessages(translationCfg, "french")
...
```

Of course for immutability's sake you could avoid using the mutable `Map` and that `var`, but this is another story.

Comment: I am going to check this way right now... thnxx for the explanations and references.